# VS Code editor, unlinking explorer pane and editor tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I click on an editor tab the focus in the explorer pane shifts to the file in question. This seems pointless to me. Can I stop this from happening? Obviously I want to continue being able to click on a file in the explorer pane and for the relevant tab to open or come up in the editor.

You may be wondering why I want this. It's because one of my open files is way down the explorer pane list and the files I want to see in the pane are up at the top of the list.

Comment: Look at the `Explorer: Auto Reveal` setting's options.

Comment: It's really the other way round that I need a solution. When I click on a file that's opened in a tab it get's highlighted in the explorer pane which is a pain as it moves the view away from the files that I want to see.

Comment: Yes, that is what that setting controls.  Set it to `false` or `focusNoScroll`.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand what it was saying when I viewed the setting but you are right it does exactly what I wanted. Glad you replied.